# Producer/Consumer with BufferBlock, how to awake periodically, even if there is no product in the buffer?

Tags: .net, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer

**Context**

In my .NET 5 console application my consumer runs as a thread (Task). Currently there is only one, but in the future it is possible to have concurrent racing consumers on the very same BufferBlock instance.

The current implementation runs fine.
I stuck with implementing the following added feature:

I would like wake up in a configured period, even the buffer is empty, and still remain in the main loop.
This use case must be distinguishable from the wake up by token's IsCancellationRequested,
but optional distinguishing it from the "product is available to consume" is not mandatory.

I do see the overload of `ReceiveAsync` with timeout, but it is not clear how `OutputAvailableAsync` is involved, which do not accepts timeout.

**Question**

How to implement to wake up in a given time period, and remain in the loop. Only in case IsCancellationRequested should break the loop

```
public class MyConsumer
{
    private readonly BufferBlock<MyProduct> _products;

    public void Start(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Run(token), token);
    }

    private async Task Run(CancellationToken token)
    {
        await ConsumeAsync(token);
    }

    private async Task ConsumeAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (await _products.OutputAvailableAsync(token))
        {
            var product = await _products.ReceiveAsync(token);
            // Consume product goes here:...

            // I would like wake up here in a configured period, even the buffer is empty.
            //
            // How to implement this timeout based wake up? (then still remain in the loop)
            // I do not even understand clearly why are we using the two waiting operations, 
            // the 1) OutputAvailableAsync(token) then 2) ReceiveAsync(token)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding *I do not even understand clearly why are we using the two waiting operations* -> you can replace `await _products.OutputAvailableAsync(token)` with `while(true)` because `ReceiveAsync` will wait until output is available, **but** you need to check whether the block is completed, and as such won't produce anything in the futue, yourself. `OutputAvailableAsync` makes it easier to exit when no more output will ever be available.

Comment: *I would like wake up here in a configured period, even the buffer is empty.* I do not understand the use case. If the buffer is empty there is no product available. Can't you create a seperate method doing whatever you want to happen and call that method at the desired time(s)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not hugely familiar with `BufferBlock`, but *in the general sense*: if an `async` API doesn't provide a timeout, you can simulate the same via a cancellation-token with a timeout - and still respect the existing token:

```cs
using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
// link the existing CancellationToken so that *it* can propagate cancellation
using var linked = token.Register(
    static s => ((CancellationTokenSource)s).Cancel(), cts, false);
// add a timeout
cts.CancelAfter(yourTimeoutHere);
// use this new combined token to do the magic
await DoSomethingAsync(cts.Token);
```

(if you're not using C# 9 or higher, remove the `static`; that just verifies that we're not causing additional allocations due to captured variables in the callback)

---

Once you have that in place, you can simply respond to *your* timeout as the incremental work, catch the `OperationCanceledException`, and do what you need. The slight caveat is knowing what state things get left in in the `DoSomethingAsync` if a cancellation happens. That will be scenario specific.

Comment: I don't think *if an async API doesn't provide a timeout* is the case here. It does support timeouts. It seems like the actual question is how the method can be entered while the method is awaiting output from the buffer block.

Comment: @PeterBons perhaps I wasn't explicit enough; I'll add a paragraph...

Comment: Thanks, I think this improves the answer greatly.

Comment: @PeterBons the .OutputAvailableAsync(token) does not provide timeout. The control flow is async wait there until either a cancellation occurs or an item is available in the buffer.